# Manipulating database output in Android strings

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to manipulate the output of an SQLite query so into two parts - KEY_DATE and KEY_ROWID + KEY_TYPE.  Here's the code without the KEY_TYPE bit:

```
    DataBaseAdapter db = new DataBaseAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    // get last test date
    int whichItem = 1;
    int upDown = 1; // use 1 for descending ordering
    Cursor mCursor = db.getLogType(whichItem, upDown);
    String[] columns = new String[] {DataBaseAdapter.KEY_DATE, DataBaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID};
    startManagingCursor(mCursor);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, mCursor, columns, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}){
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled(){ 
            return false; 
        } 
        public boolean isEnabled(int position){ 
            return false; 
        }
    };
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();
```

It works fine, but when I replace:

```
    String[] columns = new String[] {DataBaseAdapter.KEY_DATE, DataBaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID};
```

with:

```
    String[] columns = new String[] {DataBaseAdapter.KEY_DATE, DataBaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID + DataBaseAdapter.KEY_TYPE};
```

it doesn't work.

All help much appreciated!

Comment: what does the '+' means to you?

Comment: Concatenate.  I've used it elsewhere without a problem, e.g. `Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_LOGTABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TYPE, KEY_DATE, KEY_NOTES}, KEY_TYPE + "=" + rowType, null, null, null, null, null);`  Have I got this wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to make a Where clause?

Comment: Found a very simple solution and added as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found a simpler answer.  The problem was really with the concatenation.  I was trying to do it in `String[] columns...` but actually what I needed to do was to concatenate at as part of the `SELECT` query and use an alias.  Hence I changed the `String[] columns` to include the column alias name `KEY_ROWID_TYPE` as follows:

```
String[] columns = new String[] {DataBaseAdapter.KEY_DATE, DataBaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID_TYPE};
```

And the query is then:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_LOGTABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TYPE, KEY_DATE, KEY_ROWID + " || \"-\" || " + KEY_TYPE + " as " + KEY_ROWID_TYPE}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

And of course I defined the `KEY_ROWID_TYPE` too.

Thanks to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in the:

```
String[] columns = new String[] {DataBaseAdapter.KEY_DATE, DataBaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID + DataBaseAdapter.KEY_TYPE}
```

You are concat strings `DataBaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID + DataBaseAdapter.KEY_TYPE` that will leads you to some new column name that is hybrid of both of them (e.g if `KEY_ROWID="_id"` and `KEY_TYPE="device"` then the new column name will be `"_iddevice"`). This might affect the result. Make sure you have column that has the same name as the concationation of these two column names I mentioned above. But if you want to include the `KEY_TYPE` in your result, add `KEY_TYPE` as separate element of the array that holds your column names. Then concat the result from both columns in result rows. (I'm assuming this is what you were trying to achieve)

```
 String[] columns = new String[] {DataBaseAdapter.KEY_TYPE, DataBaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID};
 List<MyResult> list = new ArrayList<MyResult>();
Cursor result_of_query = database.query(DataBaseAdapter.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
           if(result_of_query.moveToFirst())
           {
               while(result_of_query.isAfterLast()==false)
               {
                  MyResult result = new MyResult();
 result.setId(result_of_query.getInt(result_of_query.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID))));
                result.setType(result_of_query.getString(result_of_query.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.KEY_TYPE))));

                   result_of_query.moveToNext();
                   list.add(result);

               }
           }

           result_of_query.close();


---

public class MyResult
{
     private String type;
     private int id;
     public void setType(String t)
     {
       type=t;
     }
    public String getType()
    {
      return type;
    }

    public void setId(int t)
     {
       id=t;
     }
    public int getId()
    {
      return id;
    }
}

---
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Can you give me an example of how I should do the concatenation please?

Comment: In your `DataBaseAdapter` class declare another `static String KEY_ROWID_TYPE = KEY_ROWID + KEY_TYPE;` and then access it `DataBaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID_TYPE`. But what you are trying to do? In the comment I might noticed that you are trying to write a Where clause...I might be wrong. Or you are trying to concatinate the data from both columns? If so. than you need to concatinate output strings instead of column names.

Comment: Hi Nikola.  I'm trying to display some concatenated data in a simple expandable list.  I thought that I could just put the output from the two database fields together (I'll probably put a space between them in due course) but it's not as easy as that!

Comment: Ofcourse it's achievable, what you have to do is to use another Adapter for your ExpandableListView that takes List/array as an argument for its constructor (e.g ArrayAdapter<String>) but before you instantiate the adapter, iterate over cursor data get the data, do the concatination you wanted and then instantiate the adapter and  pass it to the expandablelistview. I hope this gave you idea.

Comment: Thanks Nikola, I see what you're saying.  Do you have an example that I could adapt please?

Comment: See my edited answer about iterating over cursor. Modify MyResult class by your needs. Where you need to concat use getId()+getType() will concat both data, with this flow: `you have the List of MyResult objects -> you get object using MyResult MRobject= list.get(position)-> MRObject is used to access methods get and set in the class...`

Answer (score 0):

I would try concatenation and then insert into array

```
 String tempStr =  DataBaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID + DataBaseAdapter.KEY_TYPE;
 String[] columns = new String[] {DataBaseAdapter.KEY_DATE,tempStr};
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to build the array correctly.  Should there be some explicit looping?